# Push a UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd to a different view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to push an add button to a different view controller and I'm not using a storyboard. The button appears but doesn't do anything when clicked. Here's the code I have:

```
-(void)pushLogin
{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[AddListingViewController alloc] init]   animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Listings";

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                             target:nil
                                  action:@selector(pushLogin)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target should be the viewcontroller, not nil

```
 UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                             target:self
                                  action:@selector(pushLogin)];
```

Comment: More correctly - `target` should be the object that implements the `action` selector. In this case (and most) it is `self`.

Comment: What a "duh" post that was. Thanks a bunch.